# Automatically insert images to translated page

Tags: 7, media, i18n-l10n

I have a bilingual D7 website. It seems odd to insert all images twice, one for the original and one for the translated version, so my question is: Is there a way to automatically insert the image I upload for my orignal site into its translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module instead of core Content Translation to provide multilingual functionality into your site, then define which fields are translatable and which are not. 
You can't reach your goal with Content Translation module only.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. But is it possible to change modules on a running site or is it advisable to keep this in mind for the next project?

Comment: Is it possible? Of course, always ;) But if it is just inconvenience and your client doesn't want to spend a lot for this migration then you should keep it in mind for future.

btw. this is a great resource about migration process (http://evolvingweb.ca/blog/upgrading-entity-translation-drupal-7)